# Function is not reading data

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I have an issue with my script. I have an editable field and button next to it. I tried to make a function that will start working after I will press the button and it will read data from my input field, hover it doesn't read any value from my input field and returns that the input is empty. Could you please suggest any possible solutions to it? I cannot change any input or button types to other ones. Full code: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-black-7mezc?file=/code.html

```js
const trigger =
  document.getElementById("poga1");
trigger.addEventListener("click", next);


function next() {
  document.getElementById("input")


  // default to no data
  let message = "there are no data!";
  const output = document.getElementById("output");

  // get the value, this will be text - trim all leading and trailing spaces 
  const value = this.value.trim();
  if (value !== "") {
    // try to convert it to an integer
    const numeric = parseInt(value);
    // check if it's a number and if it matches what was entered
    if (isNaN(numeric) || numeric != value) {
      message = "not a number";
    } else
    if (numeric >= 1 && numeric <= 3) {
      message = "not passed";
    } else if (numeric >= 4 && numeric <= 10) {
      message = "passed!";
    } else {
      message = "wrong data";
    }
  }
  output.textContent = message;
};
```

```html
<span contenteditable="true"><p id="input"></p></span>
<button id="poga1">Check!</button>
<span contenteditable="true"><p id="output">Vispirms ievadi datus!</p></span>
```

Comment: What is the first line of the `next` function doing? It doesn't seem to be doing anything

Comment: `next` is on the button, not the editable. `input` is empty. `output` has data. You need to get the data from the field you want--you seem to be skipping this step.

Comment: I tought by running function "next" it will get element by id input and them run the checks on this value. I am wrong?

Comment: Spans don't have a value property, form elements do. You probably want the innerHTML

Comment: @j08691 Which line should i replace with the innerHTML?

Comment: The one where you get the `value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to read the content of the element with an id `input`, then you have to change the line

```
const value = this.value.trim();
```

to

```
const value = input.innerText.trim();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, so small thing but it fixed everything! Love from me!